# update and insert MySQL DB on AWS RDS with local MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, mysql-replication

I have created an RDS database and have used mysqldump to send all my local data to that remote database using the following commands:

```
$ mysqldump -u root fishDB > localDB.sql
$ mysql -h fishinstance.xxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -u mola -p fishDB < localDB.sql
```

Since AWS usage is costly and the database is about 1Gb (but only 5mb is new) and growing, I would like to setup a daily update and insert revised or new data instead of doing a data dump every time. I've read about possible solutions from [Accessing to a remote mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484452/accessing-to-a-remote-mysql-db-in-trigger) and [Using Trigger to update table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910617/using-trigger-to-update-table-in-another-database).  Although both solution discussions are very compelling, after checking my local database, I discover that I do not have FEDERATED.  I do have MyISAM.

I've also looked at [Amazon RDS documentations](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.html) and found it to be very limiting and can't figure out how to setup this procedure.  Could you help me with setting up this update?  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Why not use native MySQL replication?

Comment: Why do you think this will reduce costs? You'll be paying for the RDS whenever it's running, even if you aren't making queries.

Comment: It seems you have a very clear idea how to keep cost down to a manageable level.  The AWS support team advised me to split my webapp into EC2 instance and RDS instance both running inside a VPC.  They told me to build the MySQL database in the RDS and the easiest way to get my database up and running was to do a mysqldump.  But now that everything is working, I need to update my RDS database.  Thanks for pointing me to the replication idea.  Should I start another question re replication setup, or can you help me with that setup, here? If it's off top, I'll start another question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to use replication for this.  If you look inside RDS's Parameter groups, you will see where to set the servers.  It is a bit more involved then simply flicking a switch, but that is definitely your best bet.  This will keep them in constant sync and as updates happen each server will receive them depending on the configuration (master/master or master slave, etc.).  You don't have to do a dump every day, and this will likely lower your I/Os which you also get billed for.  I believe binary logging also has to be on if you don't already have it.